# Who are the authors in this facade?

Tags: identification-request

Can someone tell me the authors on the Oscar Wilde restaurant in NYC?

[image: Facade of the 'Oscar Wilde restaurant' in NYC.]

Comment: I only recognize Becket and O'Nolan so I imagine they're all Irish given the connection to Oscar Wilde. But no James Joyce?

Comment: I see George Bernard Shaw. You could maybe go to the bar's Facebook page or website and ask your question there. It looks like a great place! I will keep looking.

Answer (score 3):

1. [Seamus Heaney](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seamus_Heaney)

[image: Seamus Heaney.]

2. [Sean O'Casey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Se%C3%A1n_O%27Casey)

[image: Sean O'Casey, Playwright, Smoking Pipe.]

3. [George Bernard Shaw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Bernard_Shaw)

[image: G. B. Shaw.]

4. [Samuel Beckett](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Beckett)
5. [William Butler Yeats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._B._Yeats)

[image: W. B. Yeats.]

6. [Brendan Behan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brendan_Behan)
7. [James Joyce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Joyce)

[image: James Joyce.]

8. [Brian O'Nolan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_O%27Nolan)

[image: Brian O'Nolan.]

9. [Patrick Kavanagh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrick_Kavanagh)

Comment: Please could you include a bit more than just Wikipedia links? Even just an image of each man taken from the internet, side-by-side with his portrait from the OP, would make this answer way better.

Comment: I've downvoted this for being essentially a link-only answer, with no supporting evidence that it's correct. If you edit some evidence (e.g. images) into the post itself, I'll be happy to upvote it instead :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor I'll try and add more information. The images are fairly easy to find. It's locating dates and photographer information that may be tricky. It may take me some time. Nice challenge, though.